# How to replace all bars of a path in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying:

```
var str = "\\\\user-nb\\d$\\temp\\tmp1\\teste.TAR";
str = str.replace(/\\"/g,'&');
```

But it doesn't work ... Any help please? Thx all

Comment: There's several questions already answered on this, e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript), maybe they don't answer explicitly your question, but please take a look. Also [this link about regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters) may be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you are trying to replace all quotes.
You want to replace all backslashes?

```
str.replace(/\\/g,'&');
```